# Delete tag - Home-Use

Tags: support, retag-request

[home-use](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/home-use) <-- Kill with fire?

Answer (score 1):

[status-workingonit](/questions/tagged/status-workingonit) as it were. Chopper and I have between us closed or migrated everything [home-use](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/home-use). One of these is one of our notorious April/May 2009 mega-questions-turned-comWiki. Some of these have high views as well. 10Ks can vote-to-delete on all of that now.

Or we can unleash the hammer. Whichever.

Answer (score 0):

We can manually retag the questions, someone will have to kill the actual tags.  We can include the [home-network](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/home-network) in the process as well; that would be best done during the weekend so as not to flood the front page.  During cleanup, we can probably work to migrate some of the questions over to SU.

Comment: I don't think we have to retag those questions...most, if not all, of them should just be deleted.

Comment: @Jason, at least a good chunk of them would be appropriate for SU or unix.SE

Comment: @Chris - All but 2 have already been migrated. So we can safely delete them here knowing that they already have a home somewhere else.

Comment: @Jason, sorry meant the "home-network" tag, not "home-use". You are correct in regards to the latter.

Comment: @Jason Plus, I'm not a fan of deleting questions unless they are absolutely shite.  Closing and migrating should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Should we have a tag burning party? We can burn some of the questions while we're at it (and when I say we, I really mean, "The Awesome Mods".
[personal-use](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/personal-use)

Comment: Well... devs have access to the burninator. I can merely merge them with their better cousins.